# Simple perl regex replacement

Tags: regex, perl

Here is my perl code:

```
my $var="[url=/jobs/]click here[/url]";
$var =~ /\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[\/url\]/<a href="\1" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699">\2</a>/g
```

I'm very new to perl so i am aware that its incorrect but how do i perform this `regex replacement` correctly.

The end result would be a transformation of `$var` to `<a href="/jobs">click here</a>`

Comment: I don't understand how you missed the substitute form. There is only 1 and you have %99 of it and seem to know regex. Where did you get the existing info from? `use strict; use warnings` should have told you something.

Comment: @zdim thanks for the reminder. your answer was great but the one after was in my opinion better. if you disagree please inform me why and ill consider changing to you.

Comment: @jkushner  Great, thank you for taking care of it.  I did _not_ mean to ask about my answer -- just so that something is marked!  Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, with all the answers you know the substitute form is  `s///`

However, with something this big you should break it up into parts
to make it easier to maintain. And also helps to get *out* of the
quagmire of *delimiter hell*.

This uses a pre-compiled regex and a callback function invoked with s///`e`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Pre-compiled regex
my $rx = qr{\[url=(.+?)\](.+?)\[/url\]};

# Callback
sub MakeAnchor {
   my ($href,$text) = @_;
   return '<a href="' . $href . '" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699">' . $text . '</a>';
}

my $input = '[url=/jobs/]click here[/url]';
$input =~ s/$rx/MakeAnchor($1,$2)/eg;

print $input;
```

Outout

`<a href="/jobs/" style="text-decoration:none;color:#336699">click here</a>`